# Simple HowTo to start C++ command line tool on OS X inside a debugger

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, gdb

I have a piece of unix software written in C++ which can be build on OSX via the usual `./configure; make; make install` steps. It's a command line tool, so no fancy GUI or something like that involved.

To get a better understanding of the code, I would like to execute the tool in a debugger. I would like the debugger to stop at the beginning of the `main` method and would then like to step through the function calls. So also no fancy requirements involved here.

My problem is, that I have quite some experiences in Windows development, but I'm new to this stuff on Unix/OSX and it's hard for me to assemble all required compile flags, tools, ... I guess I have just to add some flags to `./configure` and should then be able to execute the resulting executable somehow using gdb. But the details are somewhat tricky and hard to figure out. Does anybody know a good resource to get started? Like "Debugging a C command line tool using gdb for dummies"? ;-)

Comment: What's the question here? "How do I debug on OSX"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to build with debugging info. You can use configure like this:

```
./configure CFLAGS=-g CPPFLAGS=-g
```

(Run `./configure --help` for more detailed help for your project.)

Then it's just a matter of starting the tool within gdb:

```
gdb ./mytool
```

If you need to pass args to the tool, use this instead:

```
gdb --args ./mytool arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Once in gdb set a breakpoint where you wnat to stop and inspect the execution:

```
break main
break sourcefile.cpp:123
```

Then start execution:

```
run
```